# plot does not appear in nnet

Tags: r, plot, neural-network

```
library(nnet)
data(iris)
attach(iris)
partition<-c(sample(1:50, 25), sample(51:100, 25), sample(101:150, 25))
train.iris<-iris[partition,]
test.iris<-iris[-partition,]
iris_nnet<-nnet(Species~., data=train.iris, size=2, decay=5e-4)
summary(iris_nnet)
y<-test.iris$Species
p<-predict(iris_nnet, test.iris, type="class")
tt<-table(y,p)
summary(tt)
test.err<-function(h.size){
  ir<-nnet(Species~., data=train.iris, size=h.size, decay=5e-4, trace=F)
  y<-test.iris$Species
  p<-predict(ir, test.iris, type="class")
  err<-mean(y != p)
  c(h.size, err)
}
out<-t(sapply(2:10, FUN=test.err))
plot(out, type="b", xlab="The number of Hidden Units", ylab="Test Error“)
```

The last plot statement does not work. I expect it to pop up plot but it doesn't.
What is wrong on that?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Oh no. How stupid I am.

```
plot(out, type="b", xlab="The number of Hidden Units", ylab="Test Error“)
```

The last punctuation's direction is wrong.

Good day for all of you!